# NPE when trying to access variable using Singleton

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, singleton

I am working on a project for college and I am using the Singleton Design Pattern to globally access a variable from any activity within my application.

I am getting this error when I run my application:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.waitronproto9.SectionsActivity$2.onClick(SectionsActivity.java:80)
```

This is the line of code it relates to:

```
Order.getInstance().setTableNumber(table);
```

This is my entire `SectionsActivity`:

```
public class SectionsActivity extends Activity{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ActionBar ab;
    Button homeBtn;
    Button viewBtn;
    Button langBtn;

    ImageView callWaiterBtn;

    public static Order order;
    public static EditText tableNum;
    public static EditText coverNum;
    int table;
    int covers;

    private OrderApplication app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_sections);

        Dialog d = createDialog();
        d.show();

        callWaiterBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.callWaiter);
        callWaiterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "A Waiter is on their way!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
    }

    public Dialog createDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SectionsActivity.this);

        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        tableNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numberEntry);
        coverNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.coversEntry);

        builder.setMessage("Order Information");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Create order object in here
                    table = Integer.parseInt(tableNum.getText().toString());
                    covers = Integer.parseInt(coverNum.getText().toString());
                    Order.getInstance().setTableNumber(table);
                    Order.getInstance().setCoverNumber(covers);
                    Toast.makeText(SectionsActivity.this, "Order Created",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This is the `Order` class:

```
public class Order {

    int tableNumber;
    int coverNumber;
    double amount;
    List<Dish> orderItems;

    private static Order instance;

    // Constructors hidden because it is singleton...
    private Order(int tableNumber, int coverNumber, double amount,
            List<Dish> orderItems) {
        super();
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
        this.coverNumber = coverNumber;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }

    private Order() {
        super();
        orderItems = new ArrayList<Dish>();
    }

    // SET THE INSTANCE
    public static void initInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Order();
        }
    }

    // RETURN INSTANCE
    public static Order getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public int getTableNumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }

    public void setTableNumber(int tableNumber) {
        this.tableNumber = tableNumber;
    }

    public int getCoverNumber() {
        return coverNumber;
    }

    public void setCoverNumber(int coverNumber) {
        this.coverNumber = coverNumber;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public List<Dish> getOrderItems() {
        return orderItems;
    }

    // Add to order
    public void addToOrder(Dish d){
        this.orderItems.add(d);
    }

    public void removeFromOrder(int position){
        this.orderItems.remove(position);
    }

    public void setOrderItems(List<Dish> orderItems) {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }
}
```

This is the `OrderApplication` class:

```
public class OrderApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initSingletons();
    }

    protected void initSingletons(){
        Order.initInstance();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Any advice is much appreciated!

STACK TRACE:

```
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at com.example.waitronproto9.SectionsActivity$2.onClick(SectionsActivity.java:80)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 04:06:14.559: E/AndroidRuntime(29562):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not instantiated your `Order`. You need to do that before trying to be able to access its methods.

Try something like this, in your `Order` class:-

```
//RETURN INSTANCE
public static Order getInstance(){
    initInstance(); // Instantiate and then return.
    return instance;
}
```

**Suggestion**:-

In your `SectionsActivity`, since you've declared `public static Order order;`, why not use it like this:-

```
order = Order.getInstance();
order.setTableNumber(table);
```

Comment: I did as you suggested with relation to the `initInstance()` and it resolved the issue. Will accept your answer when SO lets me. What do you mean about your second suggestion? Do you mean I can do this instead of calling `initInstance()`?

Comment: No, I meant, since you already have declared that `Order order`, why not use it by assigning your `Order.getInstance()` to it, as I've mentioned in my response. This is just a suggestion though.

Comment: Oh sorry I read your response wrong, I see what you mean! It's 4am where I am and I've been working through then night, a little bit groggy @ this stage! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Call initInstance() inside getInsance().

Although, you might want to reconsider your use of Singletons. There's some debate on whether this is good practice or not, I wont comment without seeing your whole application.

Answer (score 0):

R.Js suggestion does eliminate the NPE but your code should work too because OrderApplication calls Order.initInstance() when it's created so the singleton should be instantiated once the SectionsActivity starts.
Unless of course you haven't declared OrderApplication in your mainfest.xml which is likely the root cause for the NPE:

```
<application
    android:name="OrderApplication"
```